# "Sign in with Google+" using Google Play Services (G+ authentication)

Tags: android, google-play-services

The app needs to authenticate using G+ (ie a "Sign In with G+"  button, and as part of that to get access to the email address and name of the user. The app does not need to use any other Google APIs. I've looked at a variety of sources of information on how to do this and it's confusing me more than helping.

This page explains how to get an auth token and account name. I suspect this is not what I need but I'm not sure:
https://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html

This page shows how to get up and running with the GoogleApiClient:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

But then this page shows how (after the above) to add a G+ Sign In button includes code that has typos and inconsistencies in it, and it's unclear how the code (which overlaps) relates to the previous page I mentioned.
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

The above pages have not helped much. I'm struggling to even get the sample code provided to compile. There's such a deep sea of boilerplate I find it really hard to see what's happening in the code. I suspect most of these samples are showing authentication as part of a wider integration to access other Google APIs - that's not what I need, I just want to authenticate the user, get a token, their email address and profile name.

There is a Play Services extras sample called "auth" that looks like it might do what's needed. But there's another sample called "plus" that some pages suggest looking at instead. Looking at both it's not obvious which is closer to what I need.

In amongst all of this it seems the G+ API has moved not so long ago, so I need to make sure I use the most recent one, in Google Play Services.

Can anyone please help me see the wood for the trees? I'm surprised getting a G+ Sign In working is so difficult. I'm overwhelmed by the amount of seemingly unhelpful documentation and confusing code sample. I've looked through a lot of questions on SO but I've yet to find anything that helps me.

Comment: the example you want to look at is the third link you provided, it is bretty much what is generated when you let android studio create an activity that has google+ signin

Comment: I did try using the template code Android Studio creates, but it won't even build, I get this: "Error:(117, 0) Could not find property 'compile' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@1d54235. Even if it were to build it's not clear how to get the user's name, and the code appears to be preparing the Activity to access other APIs which I do not need it to do.

The third link above was not helpful for me, as the code samples provided do not compile - the sample code is not complete, and again it doesn't explain how to get the user's name.

Comment: To be more specific about the code not building. The sample references  the following that are not defined: RC_SIGN_IN, getIntentSender() method (doesn't exist on com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult), and resolveSignInErrors(). I expect the latter is meant to be resolveSignInError() but the others are not defined. I can set a value for the activity response code, but it should be defined in the sample. The code also includes the syntactically incorrect "mIntentInProgress == false" as a statement.

Comment: I never had a problem building when I used that but anyway to get the person name you need to wait until `onConnected` is called then use `Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);` and `person.getDisplayName()`

Comment: I've set the activity response code int, fixed the typo on the method name, and also fixed the getIntentSender() method by replacing it with  startResolutionForResult() which apparently replaced it over a year ago. It looks like the API changed and Google didn't bother to update the page. But although it now builds, the app fails with a NPE relating to mConnectionResult, which now I look is not defined anywhere in the sample source code, aside from onConnectionFailed(). This sample code is a joke.